# How to size the image normalization in handwriting recognition?

Tags: image-processing, image-recognition

Handwriting number recognition problem : how can i normalize the hand wiring number image  ?someone can help?

Comment: Normalize in what sense? Intensity? Scale? Location?

Comment: Scale. The images in the same scale, then i can extract the features.Is there good idea to zoom image?

Comment: which library and language do you use? if OpenCV, use resize function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out how the MNIST dataset is curated here:

http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/index.html

To quote the relevant section:

> The original black and white (bilevel) images from NIST were size normalized to fit in a 20x20 pixel box while preserving their aspect ratio. The resulting images contain grey levels as a result of the anti-aliasing technique used by the normalization algorithm. the images were centered in a 28x28 image by computing the center of mass of the pixels, and translating the image so as to position this point at the center of the 28x28 field.
>
> With some classification methods (particuarly template-based methods,
>   such as SVM and K-nearest neighbors), the error rate improves when the
>   digits are centered by bounding box rather than center of mass. If you
>   do this kind of pre-processing, you should report it in your
>   publications.